# Getting undefined variable ERROR, but I am sure it's defined

Tags: php

I spend lots of time trying to fix this issue but still couldn't fix it and I would appreciate someone's help. I have cleared browser cache and even changed the browser, still having the same issue.

I have multiple variables that is defined in my PHP code, but I keep this annoying error that says some variables are not defined here is my error logs:

> Notice: Undefined index: post_tags in /home/u155301883/domains/***/public_html/cms/admin/includes/add_posts.php on line 14
>
> Notice: Undefined index: post_content in /home/u155301883/domains/***/public_html/cms/admin/includes/add_posts.php
>    on line 15

my code:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['create_post'])){

        $post_title = $_POST['title'];
        $post_author = $_POST['author'];
        $post_catagory_id = $_POST['post_catagory_id'];
        $post_status = $_POST = ['post_status'];

        $post_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $post_image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

        $post_tags = $_POST['post_tags'];
        $post_content = $_POST['post_content'];
        $post_date = date('d-m-y');
        $post_comment_count = 4;
        move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "../images/$post_image" );

    }
?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Post Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_category">Post Category ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="post_catagory_id">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Post Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="author">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Post Status</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="post_status">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Post Images</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Post Tags</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="post_tags">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_content">Post Content</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="post_content" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="create_post" value="Publish Post">
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Simple test, add a `print_r($_POST);`  to the PHP code to see whats in there

Comment: If it is empty, it won't be set. Same for checkboxes. `$post_tags = $_POST['post_tags'] ?? '';`

Comment: The problem is `$post_status = $_POST = ['post_status'];`

Comment: Good job RamRaider! I haven't even seen that, thank you very much for your help!! Wish you a good day.